# How to run two Spring Boot microservices in a single JUnit test?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, spring-boot-test

I have two Spring Boot REST microservices, let's call them A and B. Let's also assume that A makes a REST call to B.

I'd like to [test the integration](https://martinfowler.com/articles/microservice-testing/#testing-integration-introduction) between A and B in a single JUnit test. That is, I'd like to write a test that ensures communication and configuration from A to B is in order.

I know I can run a single microservice in Spring's "built-in" testing web server using the [@`SpringBootTest`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.x/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-working-with-random-ports) annotation on my test.

Is it possible to run both A and B simultaneously in a single test in a similar fashion?

Comment: In my opinion the focus of JUnit are unit tests not integration tests.

Comment: Thanks @snap. I agree JUnit is focused on unit tests but that does not disqualify it from being a useful driver of all kinds of other tests, ex: end to end tests with Selenium. The focus of my question is how to run 2 instances of Spring's test web server in a single test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I've managed to pull if off by removing `@SpringBootTest` from my JUnit test and instantiating the two microservices using a `SpringApplicationBuilder` each.

A is `Demo1Application` and B is `Demo2Application`:

```
@Test
public void test1() {
    HashMap<String, Object> props1 = new HashMap<>();
    props1.put("server.port", 8092);

    SpringApplicationBuilder builder1 = new SpringApplicationBuilder(Demo1Application.class);
    builder1
        .properties(props1)
        .run(new String[]{""});

    HashMap<String, Object> props2 = new HashMap<>();
    props2.put("server.port", 8093);

    SpringApplicationBuilder builder2 = new SpringApplicationBuilder(Demo2Application.class);
    builder2
    .properties(props2)
        .run(new String[]{""});
}
```